# How can I stop all current jquery before loading more?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm running Lightbox evolution, though using it over several pages, and I believe the problem is when I load a different page up with a different gallery it reloads the same script and gives all sorts of problems!

Only code I've got for lightbox on my page is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.lightbox').lightbox();
  });
</script>
```

EDIT: All sorted, had it loading on the index page and then on each gallery page, now is just loaded when the site loads up with index.

Comment: Post some more code, this doesn't help. Do you have more javascript on that page?

Comment: @AlexBay Just fixed it, had it loading on the index page, then was loading it again with each page, soo simple, but had me scratching my head for a few days!